# php - regex to return ip addresses from lines of text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to capture ip addresses in lines of text. Right now it's kind of screwed up. My code returns ip addresses when lines of text don't contain ip addresses and sometimes it returns "Script)". What am I doing wrong? I would like to return the ip addresses of lines that actually have them, and return nothing if they don't.

Text

```
2014-06-02 11:53:54.410 -0700   Information 638 NICOLE  Client "123456" opening a connection from "123456.local (207.230.229.204)" using "Go 13.0.4 [fmapp]".
2014-06-02 11:54:52.504 -0700   Information 98  NICOLE  Client "123456 (123456.local) [207.230.229.204]" closing database "FMServer_Sample" as "Admin".
2014-06-02 12:07:33.433 -0700   Information 638 NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect]" opening a connection from "207.230.229.204 (207.230.229.204)" using "Win Chrome 35.0 [fmwebdirect]".
2014-06-02 13:05:00.088 -0700   Information 638 NICOLE  Client "Showare Update" opening a connection from "FileMaker Script" using "Server 13.0v1 [fmapp]".
2014-06-02 13:05:22.366 -0700   Information 98  NICOLE  Client "Showare Update (FileMaker Script)" closing database "cac" as "opus".
2014-06-02 12:08:04.165 -0700   Information 98  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (207.230.229.204) [207.230.229.204]" closing database "FMServer_Sample" as "Admin".
```

PHP

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/', $line, $ip_matches)) {
    $client_ips = $ip_matches[1];
}

print "<pre>;
print_r($client_ips);
print "</pre>";
```

Output

```
207.230.229.204
207.230.229.204
207.230.229.204
207.230.229.204
207.230.229.204
Script)
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$client_ips` on every loop iteration. A variable can only contain one value at once.

Comment: ..unless its an array `$client_ips[] = $ip_matches[1];`

Comment: And that's not the actual regex you used. The `^` anchors `$` wouldn't make it match on any line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider removing the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors seeing how your IP addresses are not at the beginning/end of the string in your provided text.

```
if (preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $line, $ip_match)) {
   echo $ip_match[0];
}
```

If you want all IP addresses, use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $line, $ip_matches);
print_r($ip_matches[0]);
```